# Android Custom Button

Tags: android, layout, button

Hi i would like to create a custom button. I have implement my custom_but.xml following various tutorials using selector/item declaration in my xml And this works fine.

What i would like to do is have a label and a value on this button. Where the label maintains its value and the value changes based on user input...

Is this possible?

[image: Example of button]

Comment: what do you exactly mean by label and a value? The text on the button? If you want to associate a fixed value with a view you can take a look at `View#setTag()`

Comment: Can you show some code? I have no idea on what to help you with.

Comment: I am trying to  to align the label to the left and the value to the right. Without hard-coding layout sizes, what i probably need is to extend the Button class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like there are two ways to go about solving this.

The android Button inherits from TextView, so it has a setText() method you can use to change its text at runtime. So, a very simple way to accomplish your goal would be concatenate your "label" string with your "value" string every time the value changes, and call setText on the button.

From within an Activity:

```
Resources res = this.getResources();
String label = res.getString(R.string.label_string);
String buttonText = label + value;
button.setText(buttonText);
```

You can obviously insert any kind of separator you like between the label and value strings.

On the other hand, it looks like you may be trying to align the label to the left and the value to the right. Without hardcoding layout sizes, I don't think you can do that with only one textView (remember a Button is a textView). Writing a new class which extends Button, adding another textView, and overriding its onDraw(Canvas) method might help.

Comment: Thank you, the second scenario you describe is what I need. I will be looking into how exactly i will extend the Button class.

Comment: Hi Cephron, I'm trying to do something similar to the above situation for that I just extends Button to a class and added the following code within the constructor, LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_button,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_button_view)); but I'm getting plain button, am I missing something or anything wrong.